# Pass multiple property names, values and set them using one mixin. Is it possible?

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

Here is a ruleset in which I have my mixins, `.greyMixin()` and  `.disabled()`. The problem is that I am unable to find a way to write multiple properties in one mixin. As one can see the result where `color` and `background` are separated. I want them in one declaration.

```
.formater(@className; @rules){
    .@{className}{
        @rules();
    }
}
.greyMixin(@property, @g, @a:1){
    @rgba: rgba(@g,@g,@g,@a);
    .mixin();
    .mixin() when((@a) < 1) and (@a > 0){
        @{property}:@rgba;
        }& when ((@a) = 1){
            @{property}:@rgba;
        }& when ((@a) = 0){
            @{property}:@rgba;
        }   
}
.disabled(@property, @g, @a:1){
    @rgba: rgba(@g,@g,@g,@a);
    @rgb:rgb(@g,@g,@g);
        .mixin();
        .mixin() when((@a) < 1) and (@a > 0){
        &:disabled,&.disabled {
            &:hover,&:focus,&:active{
                @{property}:@rgba;
            }
        }& when ((@a) = 1){
            &:disabled,&.disabled { 
                &:hover,&:focus,&:active{
                    @{property}:@rgb;
                }
            }
            }& when ((@a) = 0){
                &:disabled,&.disabled { 
                    &:hover,&:focus,&:active{
                        @{property}:@rgba;
                    }
                }
                }
        }
}
.formater(colourclass;{
    .greyMixin(color,25,1);
    .greyMixin(background,110,0.8);
    .disabled(color,240,0.8);
    .disabled(background, 10,0.4)});
```

**and the result is:**

```
.colourclass {
    color: #191919;
    background: rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.8);
}
.colourclass:disabled:hover,
.colourclass.disabled:hover,
.colourclass:disabled:focus,
.colourclass.disabled:focus,
.colourclass:disabled:active,
.colourclass.disabled:active {
    color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.8);
}
.colourclass:disabled:hover,
.colourclass.disabled:hover,
.colourclass:disabled:focus,
.colourclass.disabled:focus,
.colourclass:disabled:active,
.colourclass.disabled:active {
    background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.4);
}
```

I am using less.js 2.5.3; Windows 7; Winless compiler 1.9.1.

Comment: Hmm, just in case, do you know you don't really need such `rgb/rgba` stuff and conditions. Less compiler always outputs non-transparent colors as hex values and transparent as rgba. Thus all these tricky color mixins and conditionals are somewhat redundant. For a grey color if one does not want to repeat the same value he can use `fade(#111 * @gray-value, @alpha-value)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this case, you can use looping and array list like in the below snippet. As you can notice, the input parameters are all arrays instead of having just a single value. Within the mixin, we can use `extract` function to extract the property, its color value and alpha based on the index and then use the loops to create the properties.

**Note:** I didn't understand why you need those guards with the `.mixin()` because all cases seem to be setting the same property and output. So, I have removed it in the below snippet.

I have done the changes only for one mixin (`.greyMixin`) but you can do the same for the other mixin also.

```
.formater(@className; @rules){
    .@{className}{
        @rules();
    }
}
.greyMixin(@properties; @g; @a:1){
  @propCount: length(@properties);
  .loop-properties(@index) when (@index > 0){
    @property: extract(@properties, @index);
    @col: extract(@g, @index);
    @alpha: extract(@a, @index);
    @rgba: rgba(@col,@col,@col,@alpha);
    @{property}:@rgba;
    .loop-properties(@index - 1);
  }
  .loop-properties(@propCount);
}
.formater(colourclass;{
    .greyMixin(color, background;25, 110;1, 0.8);
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to add colours not be the value, but by the colour variable for value, so that when I change the primary colour all the corresponding colours change according to the hue and saturation levels.

Comment: I have a set of variables ATprimary: rgb(60,110,210); ATsecondary:spin(ATprimary, -60); and a list of gray colours ATgr01:luma(ATprimary);ATgr02:luma(ATsecondary); I will be passing these (ATgr01, ATgr02) variables.

Comment: can we not use individual channels like red();green(); and blue(); and avoid JS somehow. It is not that I am an expert in lesscss, but learning it. As with JS I have little to no knowledge.

Comment: "whereas the extract functions output is always a string." - **No**. `extract` outputs the same type the value was originally. E.g. `extract("foo" 1 whatever red, 4)` outputs normal color object (equal to `red`/`#f00`).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: That is interesting because I am sure I tried passing the output of `extract` function to the `rgba()` function and it didn't work but now when I try it out at less2css.org it is working. Was there any changes to this function at anytime?

Comment: @vssadineni; It seems like we can use the `rgba()` function directly on the values obtained from the `extract` function. I got an error when I tried this earlier but it seems like I must have made some other mistake. Please make a note of the updates to the answer.

Comment: @Harry No, there were no changes in `extract`. In other words the snipped can be simplified to [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/6d082e9ee7d291fc6f76) (Not counting of course that since the OP uses predefined set of colors (as what we usually do with preprocessors) the whole Q snippet made around `gray` function becomes useless, since the only thing he needs actually is a mixin with detached ruleset arg to set `.disabled:*` selectors. But the story is more for code review or so).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Thank you very much :) I must have made a mistake somewhere in the code earlier.

Answer (score 0):

earlier I had an issue where in the output I got 
    background: rgba(#646464,#646464,#646464,0.8); 
so I removed the @col: rgba(@{col},@{col},@{col},@{alpha});

```
.colourMixin(@properties; @var){
    @pcount:length(@properties);
    .recurP(@index) when (@index > 0){
        @property: extract(@properties, @index);
        @colour: extract(@var, @index);
        @{property}:@colour;
        .recurP(@index - 1);
    }
        .recurP(@pcount);
}
```

now it is taking a variable.

Comment: @Harry greyMixin() can be used for grayscale output and colourMixin() for any colour.  thank you

Comment: Ok, I was expecting the input to be the r/g/b values based on the question but it seems like you are actually passing the color as-is and that's why you'd have got the output as `rgba(#646464,#646464,#646464,0.8);`.

Comment: Problem that I faced was that at first when I coded it did not take variable, I had errors so I tried with working with r/g/b and it helped me with gray scale and their opacity.

Comment: ATgr01:rgb(100,100,100); when compiled it is in#646464 HEX code.